# How does one find a pixels location from image.pixel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, screenshot, python-mss

So, i have this script which works, it prints out all the pixels that have and rgb value of (102,102,102) but i don't know how I would be able to now get that pixels location and click it.. any suggestions?

edit: by pixels location i mean the pixels x,y coordinates

```
import pyautogui
import time
from PIL import Image
import mss
import mss.tools
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import colorsys


time.sleep(3)


def shootfunc(xc, yc):
    pyautogui.click(xc, yc)

gameregion = [71, 378, 328, 530]

foundpxl = 0

xx = 0
while xx <= 300:
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        region = {'top': 0, 'left': 0, 'width': 1920, 'height': 1080}
        imgg = sct.grab(region)
        pxls = imgg.pixels


        for pxl in pxls:
            for pxll in pxl:
                if pxll == (102, 102, 102) or pxl == "(255, 255, 255)" or pxl == [255, 255, 255]:
                    foundpxl = pxll
                    print(foundpxl)
        xx = xx + 1
        time.sleep(.1)
```

Comment: Mmmm... you have a list of pixels (presumably several pixels if it's a list) and you want to click on it (presumably one pixel, else you would say *"them"*)... Which is it please? Is there a list or just one?

Answer (score 1):

You can [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) any sequence you iterate over. This returns the index of the element and the element:

```
>>> for i, e in enumerate('abc'):
...     print(i, e)
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

So, you can make use of this to find the row and column of the pixel:

```
for row, pxl in enumerate(pxls):
    for col, pxll in enumerate(pxl):
        ...
```

Comment: ok, so this isn't exactly what i needed, i should have explained better, I need to find pxl's x and y coordinates, how may i do this, if possible with my for loop?

Comment: `x` is `col`, `y` is `row`.